# How to deal with Rails attachments being nil when editing my resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm new to ActiveStorage.

I have a model called Landing with an attachment `:image`. (I'm using ActiveStorage).

When creating a new record everything goes fine, but when you update any attribute, image gets deleted unless you upload the attachment again. **Why is this? Do I need to explicitly say to my controller to handle the attachment logic if no new attachment is uploaded? No helpers for this built-in?**

**In my form, I have this input:**

```
<%= f.file_field :image, class: "rounded input w-full my-2" %>
```

**In my controller**

```
  def update
      if @landing.update(landing_params)
        redirect_to admin_landings_path, notice: "Actualizado con éxito :)"
      else
        render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
```

**My model**

```
  has_one_attached :image do |attachable|
    attachable.variant(:thumb, resize_to_fill: [500, 500])
    attachable.variant(:big, resize_to_fill: [1200, 1200])
  end
```

Comment: Are you passing the `@landing` model instance to the form builder?

Comment: @max yes, I found out a solution (posted)

Answer (score 0):

With ActiveStorage and `has_many_attached` relationships, we need to add this to production and development environments:

```
config.active_storage.replace_on_assign_to_many = false
```

This way worked for me.